# Query XDocument based on the depth of the node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML and I want to be able to query the XML based on the depth of it. I am aware of the depth before hand.

UPDATED QUESTION:
I have the following XML and I want to be able to query the XML based on if the nodes are repetitive.

So, this is my XML

```
<Books>
  <BookID>12345</BookID>
  <BookName>BookName</BookName>
  <Authors>
    <Author>
      <Name>AuthorNameOne</Name>
      <City>New York</City>
    </Author>
    <Author>
      <Name>AuthorNameTwo</Name>
      <City>New York</City>
    </Author>
  </Authors>
</Books>
```

Via XDocument I want to be able to query this XML and get node names for the elements where there is repetitive data such as Authors. Or I want to be able to query it based on the Depth of the Node.

UPDATED QUESTION: 
Via XDocument I want to be able to query this XML and get node names for the elements where there is repetitive data such as Authors.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well which are you trying to achieve? The "where there is repetitive data" requires a *lot* more information - and "based on the depth of the node" isn't terribly clear either. You say you're "aware of the depth beforehand" - so what do you need to query? Sample input and expected output would be useful, too. Also, it's odd that your XML has a `Books` element with a `BookID` directly within it - I'd expect a `Book` element in between just like you've got `Authors` with `Author` inside it.

Comment: Also, it doesn't help that you hadn't fully indented all the XML - if you're asking about the depth, please make it easy to visually spot the depth of each element!

Comment: As @JonSkeet mentioned your xml structure doesn't make that much sense, but it might just be that the indentation is off.  For example you would expect to find one or more `Book` elements under the `Books` node.  Locating repetitive nodes is easy with LINQ, but you want to make sure that your xml structure is set up properly first.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question now. Please have a look. Basically I want to be able to retrieve names like "Authors" where there are multiple child elements.

Comment: @JNYRanger : Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question now. Please have a look. Basically I want to be able to retrieve names like "Authors" where there are multiple child elements.

Comment: Just repeating "get node names for the elements where there is repetitive data such as Authors" doesn't actually make it any clearer. Basically you've said the same unclear thing several times - and it still looks like you've got two different questions here, one based on repetitive data and one based on node depth, *neither* of which is clear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

Your XML still doesn't really make sense, but I'm putting together this answer hoping that it will at least point you in the right direction.  I'm going to completely ignore the portion of your question that references node depth because I'm not really sure how it applies to the following question that you posted:

> Via XDocument I want to be able to query this XML and get node names for the elements where there is repetitive data such as Authors.

Here's how to do just that simple type query assuming that your `XDocument` is named xml:

```
List<XElement> repeatedNodes = new List<XElement>();
for(XElement node in xml.Descendants())
{
      if(node.Parent.Elements(node.Name).Count() > 1))
      {
           repeatedNodes.Add(node);
      }
 }
```

Here's the same code compressed into a lambda that will provide you with an `IEnumerable<XElement>` containing all of the elements that would go into the `List` in my first example:

```
var dupes = xml.Descandants().Where(n => n.Parent.Elements(n.Name).Count() > 1);
```

This algorithm will look at every node in the xml tree and then from the parent of the current node it will count how many nodes with that same name exist.  If that number is greater than one it will add it to our list of repeated nodes.  This does not care what depth the current node is and it will only count duplicate named nodes at the same depth.  Additionally this algorithm will put dupes in the List structure, but you can add in your own logic to prevent it from doing that or use a different structure that doesn't allow duplicates.